# How to delete previous database snapshot using regex?

Tags: powershell

We are restoring a database called ***Cube1*** as "snapshots" using below command.

```
$CUBE = "$CUBE-Snapshot-$dateStamp"
Restore-ASDatabase -Server $Target_Server -RestoreFile $BFile -Name $CUBE -Security:$SecurityChoice -AllowOverwrite -ErrorAction Stop
```

However, this is supposed to run weekly indefinitely and our server memory capacity will be  diminished leading to performance issues eventually, which we don't want.

[image: snapshots]

Therefore, I'd like to delete existing snapshots, so ultimate result would be something like this (1 snapshot only weekly):

[image: 1snapshot]

I tried the following:

```
Import-Module sqlserver
$AnalysisServer = New-Object Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Server  
$AnalysisServer.connect("$Target_Server")
$AnalysisServer.Databases["*$CUBE-Snapshot*"].Drop()
```

and the drop operation failed.

> You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.

When specifying manually the snapshot name:

```
$AnalysisServer.Databases["Cube1-Snapshot-05-30-2021-0314PM"].Drop()
```

The drop operation succeeds.

I suppose I need to use some sort of regex then since wildcards didn't seem to work for the name, so how do I accomplish that?

Comment: Could you just capture the names in a variable and iterate through each one dropping then with a foreach loop?

Comment: @AbrahamZinala i could but i would still need to wildcard the DB names anyways so that im only targeting cubes with "snapshot" in the name...so im back to square 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `[...]` to index into the `.DataBases` collections corresponds to the parameterized [`.Item[]` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.analysisservices.databasecollection.item?view=analysisservices-dotnet), which supports (a) targeting a database by *numerical index* or (b) by *verbatim name* - using *patterns* to match database names is *not* supported.

Therefore, you need to filter the database collection explicitly, which you can do with the [`.Where()` array method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Arrays#where), combined with [member-access enumeration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44620191/45375), which allows you to call the `.Drop()` method on every matching database:

```sh
$AnalysisServer.Databases.Where({ $_.Name -like "*$CUBE-Snapshot*" }).Drop()
```

Note: If *no* databases match, the above will generate a statement-terminating error; to avoid that, use a two-step approach:

```sh
$matchingDbs = $AnalysisServer.Databases.Where({ $_.Name -like "*$CUBE-Snapshot*" })
if ($matchingDbs) { $matchingDbs.Drop() }
```

To delete all snapshots *except the most recent one*, based on the naming convention shown in the question:

```sh
$matchingDbs = $AnalysisServer.Databases.Where({ $_.Name -like "*$CUBE-Snapshot*" })
if ($matchingDbs.Count -ge 2) { 
  ($matchingDbs | Sort-Object Name -Descending | Select-Object -Skip 1).Drop() 
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that works :) ! I adjusted the logic a bit to accomodate for customized retention, `if ($matchingDbs.Count -ge $SnapshotRetentionFrequency) { ($matchingDbs | Sort-Object Name -Descending | Select-Object -Skip ($SnapshotRetentionFrequency - 1)).Drop() }`